# what is the best way to test the performance of a program in linux

Tags: linux, c++11

Suppose I write a program, then I make some "optimization" for the code.
In my case I want to test how much the new feature `std::move` in C++11 can improve the performance of a program.
I would like to check whether the "optimization" do make sense.

Currently I test it by the following steps:

1. write a program(without `std::move`) , compile ,get binary file m1
2. optimize it(using `std::move`), compile, get binary file m2
3. use command "time" to compare the time consuming:

   ```
   time ./m1 ; time ./m2
   ```

**EDITED:**

In order to get the statistical result, it was needed to run the test thousands of times.

Is there any better ways to do that or is there some tools can help on it ?

Comment: As a first step, that's always a good idea, because it's simple. Just make sure that your runtime is significant. If you're trying to see an improvement in the millisecond range, you're doomed, but if the improvement is in the second range, it's something. Try it with the big stuff first, just to see if it's worth the effort.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are several tools (among others) that can do profiling for you:

- [GNU gprof](http://www.cs.utah.edu/dept/old/texinfo/as/gprof_toc.html)
- [google gperftools](http://code.google.com/p/gperftools/)
- [intel VTune amplifier](http://software.intel.com/en-us/intel-vtune-amplifier-xe) (part of the intel XE compiler package)
- [kernel perf](https://perf.wiki.kernel.org/index.php/Main_Page)
- [AMD CodeXL](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/codexl/) (successor of AMD CodeAnalyst)-
- [Valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)

Some of them require a specific way of compilation or a specific compiler. Some of them are specifically good at profiling for a given processor-architecture (AMD/Intel...).

Since you seem to have access to C++11 and if you just want to measure some timings you can use `std::chrono`.

```
#include <chrono>
#include <iostream>
class high_resolution_timer
{
private:
  typedef std::chrono::high_resolution_clock clock;
  clock::time_point m_time_point;
public:
  high_resolution_timer (void) 
    : m_time_point(clock::now()) { }
  void restart (void) 
  { 
    m_time_point = clock::now(); 
  }
  template<class Duration>
  Duration stopover (void) 
  { 
    return std::chrono::duration_cast<Duration>
           (clock::now()-m_time_point);  
  }
}; 

int main (void)
{
  using std::chrono::microseconds;
  high_resolution_timer timer;

  // do stuff here

  microseconds first_result = timer.stopover<microseconds>();
  timer.restart();

  // do other stuff here

  microseconds second_result = timer.stopover<microseconds>();

  std::cout << "First took " << first_result.count() << " x 10^-6;";
  std::cout << " second took " << second_result.count() << " x 10^-6.";
  std::cout << std::endl;

}
```

But you should be aware that there's almost no sense in optimizing several milliseconds of overall runtime (if your program runtime will be >= 1s). You should instead time highly repetitive events in your code (if there are any, or at least those which are the bottlenecks). If those improve significantly (and this can be in terms of milli or microseconds) your overall performance will likely increase, too.

Answer (score 1):

In general measuring performance using a simple time comparison, e.g. `endTime-beginTime` is always a good start, for a rough estimation.

Later on you can use a *profiler*, like *Valgrind* to get measures of how different parts of your program is performing.

With profiling you can measure  space (memory) or time complexity of a program, usage of particular instructions or frequency/duration of function calls.

There's also [AMD CodeAnalyst](http://developer.amd.com/tools-and-sdks/heterogeneous-computing/amd-codeanalyst-performance-analyzer/) if you want more advanced profiling functionality using a GUI. It's free/open source.